# Deploy Rule Service WSO2 Business Rule Server

Tags: wso2, rule-engine, business-rules

I was trying to deploy a rule service with WSO2 Business Rule Server

I exactly followed this link 
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BRS200/Creating+and+Deploying+the+Rule+Service#CreatingandDeployingtheRuleService-RuleServiceWizard

I also made the jar file from 3 different class files: 
OrderAccept.class OrderReject.class and PlaceOrder.class

I am trying to deploy the server with wizard in the end I got this error

```
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask. runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Not found : samples.userguide
.PlaceOrder
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.findClass(Deploymen
tClassLoader.java:92)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(Deploymen
tClassLoader.java:280)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at org.wso2.carbon.rule.common.config.HelperUtil.processFactDefaultValue
s(HelperUtil.java:43)
```

Anyone could help me where I might make mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your jar files are not properly picked. One reason I can think of it, your axis2 archive has wrong folder structure. I am talking about the rule service upload mechanism. You may see there is a folder structure recommended in the documentation. After creating the .aar file, extract it and see whether you have the same folder structure. If it differs from the recommended one, your jar files will not get picked.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same example and it's also giving me the same error(both methods, Rule service Upload and Rule Service Wizard). The folder structure that @Amila was suggesting seems to be ok according to the documentation. What I recently found is this link http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/05/eclipse-plugin-wso2-business-rules-server from which I quote "Previously WSO2 BRS artifacts (aar/car) were created using the web UI rule wizard or creating the artifact by combining several artifacts. With the new WSO2 Developer Studio plug-in for rule services, one can easily create a complete deployable BRS artifact using the Eclipse IDE. Developers can easily create WSO2 BRS artifacts using this tool, and deploy it in the WSO2 Business Rules Server." What I'm guessing is that this new method/tool would substitute the "old" methods(upload and wizard). Give it a try.